# set net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0 in Pod

Tags: kubernetes, kernel, sysctl

I would like to set `net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0` in Pods of my k8s cluster, However it gives me error:

> sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_timestamps: No such file or directory"

Same issue with container directly created with `docker run` command. Anyway to set the parameter in container/Pod? Thanks.

Comment: my only guess is  that the image you are using does not mount `/proc/sys/` for some reason. can you try to run vannilla ubuntu image (`docker run -t -i --name testUbuntu ubuntu:bionic bash -i`) and see if the mentioned file is there?

Comment: First, show us the real kubernetes yaml code you run with. Second, make sure you follow this url properly https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/#setting-sysctls-for-a-pod

Answer (score 2):

In Kubernetes `sysctl` have been grouped into `safe` and `unsafe`.

> In addition to proper namespacing, a  *safe*  sysctl must be properly  *isolated*  between pods on the same node. This means that setting a  *safe*  sysctl for one pod
>
> - must not have any influence on any other pod on the node
> - must not allow to harm the node’s health
> - must not allow to gain CPU or memory resources outside of the resource limits of a pod.
>
> By far, most of the  *namespaced*  sysctls are not necessarily considered  *safe*. The following sysctls are supported in the  *safe*  set:
>
> - `kernel.shm_rmid_forced`,
> - `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range`,
> - `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies`.

By default all `safe sysctls` are enabled by default.
All `unsafe sysctls`  are disabled and need to be allowed manually by cluster admin on each node.

> ```sh
> kubelet --allowed-unsafe-sysctls \
>  'kernel.msg*,net.core.somaxconn' ...
> ```
>
> For  [Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/), this can be done via the  `extra-config`  flag:
>
> ```sh
> minikube start --extra-config="kubelet.allowed-unsafe-sysctls=kernel.msg*,net.core.somaxconn"...
> ```
>
> Only  *namespaced*  sysctls can be enabled this way.

This is mentioned on [Enabling Unsafe Sysctls](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/#enabling-unsafe-sysctls) k8s documentation.

As for, [Setting Sysctls for a Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/#setting-sysctls-for-a-pod):

> A number of sysctls are  *namespaced*  in today’s Linux kernels. This means that they can be set independently for each pod on a node. Only namespaced sysctls are configurable via the pod securityContext within Kubernetes.
>
> The following sysctls are known to be namespaced. This list could change in future versions of the Linux kernel.
>   -   `kernel.shm*`,
>   -   `kernel.msg*`,
>   -   `kernel.sem`,
>   -   `fs.mqueue.*`,
>   -   The parameters under  `net.*`  that can be set in container networking namespace. However, there are exceptions (e.g.,  `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max`  and  `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_expect_max`  can be set in container networking namespace but they are unnamespaced).
>
> Sysctls with no namespace are called  *node-level*  sysctls. If you need to set them, you must manually configure them on each node’s operating system, or by using a DaemonSet with privileged containers.
>
> Use the pod securityContext to configure namespaced sysctls. The securityContext applies to all containers in the same pod.
>
> This example uses the pod securityContext to set a safe sysctl  `kernel.shm_rmid_forced`  and two unsafe sysctls  `net.core.somaxconn`  and  `kernel.msgmax`. There is no distinction between  *safe*  and  *unsafe*  sysctls in the specification.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: sysctl-example
spec:
  securityContext:
    sysctls:
    - name: kernel.shm_rmid_forced
      value: "0"
    - name: net.core.somaxconn
      value: "1024"
    - name: kernel.msgmax
      value: "65536"
  ...
```

You may be interested in reading following questions on StackOverflow [Pros and cons of disabling TCP timestamps](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/111794/pros-and-cons-of-disabling-tcp-timestamps) and [What benefit is conferred by TCP timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880383/what-benefit-is-conferred-by-tcp-timestamp).

Comment: Hello Crou, I checked doc for kubernetes.io, seems it is an issue of docker. Basically, I want to close tcp_timestamp parameter in any Pod, it failed when I run "sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0" command  after exec to the pod

Comment: You cannot do that inside a pod. You need to set specs so this can be enabled.